# Where is order ID generated?

Tags: checkout, orders, onepage-checkout, quote

I have been overriding the function saveOrderAction in the OnepageController.php (/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers) with my custom code.

I have implemented the logic for this successfully. I believe at this point at the start of the function as the order hasn't been completed there is no order ID. Instead I have access to the 'quote ID'.

What I need to do now is find out where the Order ID is generated for the order. My first question is which file/function is best to override for when the Order ID is created?

My second question is, is there a way to link the quote ID to the Order ID which is generated?

Essentially my aim is to get the order ID of the currently ordered items so I can do further custom processing.

---

My observer code is through this path: /local/James/Aftercheckout

config.xml - /local/James/Aftercheckout/etc

Observer.php - /local/James/Aftercheckout/Model

Contents of config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>

    <James_Aftercheckout>

        <version>0.1.0</version>

    </James_Aftercheckout>

    </modules>        
<global>        
    <events>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
            <observers>
                <james_aftercheckout_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>James_Aftercheckout_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>test</method>
                </james_aftercheckout_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

Code for Observer.php :

```
class James_Aftercheckout_Model_Observer
{   

public function test($observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $incrementId = $quote->getReservedOrderId();


    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message! .".$incrementId;
    $from = "randomemail@example.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
}
```

Comment: You are referring to the physical ID (the table increment id), the one that looks like 4, 17 and so on? or the order increment id, the one that looks like 100000054?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the order increment id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The increment id of the order is created when the order is submitted, in this method `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder()`. The line responsible for the creation is `$quote->reserveOrderId();`.
If you want to access it you can hook onto the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`.
You will be able to get the increment id in you observer like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer){//observer for the event
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $incrementId = $quote->getReservedOrderId();
    //do stuff
}
```